# Fundamental theorem of calculus with 2-variables integrand

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, improper-integrals, partial-derivative

I have an equation in the form

$$\int_x^\infty f(x,y) \, dy = \int_x^\infty g(y) \, dy$$

from which I would like to derive a relation between the functions $f$ and $g$.

If I take the partial derivative w.r. to $x$ of both sides, I get, using the fundamental theorem of calculus,

$$\partial_x \left( \int_x^\infty f(x,y) \, dy\right) = -g(x)$$

However, I don't know what to do with the first term.

Is there anything I can conclude about it without having to find an analytical expression for the integral?

Comment: you can refer to Leibniz integral rule. under certain conditions on your function $f(x,y)$  you can differentiate under the integral.

Answer (score 1):

You can employ chain rule in two dimensions. Define
$$h(x,z)=\int_z^\infty f(z,y)\, dy$$
and 
$$w(x)=(x,x).$$
Then you have
$$\int_x^\infty f(x,y)\, dy = h(w(x)),$$
hence you can derive the composition on the right hand side by chain rule:
$$\partial_x\left(\int_x^\infty f(x,y)dy\right)= -f(x,y)+\int_x^\infty\partial_x f(x,y)dy$$